# cannot install tensorflow on pip (python 3.7)

Tags: python, tensorflow

hello I am having issues with installing tensoflow (for CPU because I don't have a gpu that works) using pip. I tried using the pip in visual studio code and the command prompt and got the same error if anyone has gotten it to work then please share how. (see the code for a command that I used and the attached photo for my error message).thanks in advance

```
pip install tensorflow
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wROFP.jpg

Comment: Make sure you follow the instructions on the website https://www.tensorflow.org/install

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip says that 3.7 is not supported, use 3.6 instead

Comment: tensorflow isn't available for python3.7 yet, I hope that changes but currently you have to work with an older release like python3.6

Comment: Is your version of Python 64bit ? As of TensorFlow 1.13.1 released on Feb 26th, you should be able to install TensorFlow on Python 3.7.

Comment: I got it to work finally. thanks to everyone who helped me out. hopefully, tensorflow will add support for Python 3.7 soon